# Where is statusDescription When .NET MVC Return HttpNotFound

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, http, web

The code like this

```
if (id == null)
{
    return HttpNotFound("Error Id");
}
//// do something ...
if (entity == null)
{
    return HttpNotFound("Null Entity");
}
//// do something ...
if (somethingError())
{
    return HttpNotFound("Something Error");
}
```

If I Request it use browser ,

I will got a 404 Page which I set before .

But where is the Error Message(statusDescription) ?

I can not find it on the Header or Raw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use [HttpException](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpexception(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
return new HttpException(404, "Some description");
```

/////////////ADDED

you can use code below

Web.config

```
<customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="~/Error">
</customErrors>
```

Controller:

```
public class ErrorController : Controller
{
  public ViewResult Index(string message)
  {
     ViewBag.ErrorMessage = message;

    return View("Error");
  }
}
```

View

```
@{
   Layout = "_Layout.cshtml";
   ViewBag.Title = "Error";
   string errorMessage = (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ViewBag.ErrorMessage))? ViewBag.ErrorMessage : " An unexpected error has occurred. Please contact the system administrator.";
 }

 <div class="row">
    <span>Error</span>
 </div>
 <div class="row">
    <div class="alert alert-error">
       @errorMessage
    </div>
 </div>
```

your code :

```
        var errorMessage = "";

        if (id == null)
        {
            errorMessage = "Error Id";
        }
        //// do something ...
        if (entity == null)
        {
            errorMessage = "Null Entity";
        }
        //// do something ...
        if (somethingError())
        {
            errorMessage = "Something Error";
        }

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(errorMessage)) return RedirectToAction("Index", "Error", new { message = errorMessage });
```

Comment: Tks answer, but HttpException is not a ActionResult

Comment: I am so sorry for response so late, 
my 404 page just a static page , 
and I set a httpErrors on my web.config .
when an 404 Error happened , 
it should be redirect to 404 Page.